# C# DataTable edit cell in specific row with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

i have a DataTable table and few TextBox controls. When I click button I need to change the "Value" collumn, where ID matches the text input.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(decimal));
table.Columns.Add("Unit", typeof(string));

string myId=txtId.Text;
decimal myValue=txtValue.Text;
```

I know how to check if ID exists in the table. How do I change the value of the field "Value"?

```
bool contains = table.AsEnumerable().Any(row => myID == row.Field<string>("ID"));
if (contains == true)
{
     //Change the value of row.Field<string>("Value")!!
}
```

Thank you for help.

EDIT: 
Here is my solution:

```
string s = "ID='" + myId + "'";
DataRow dr = table.Select(s).FirstOrDefault();
dr["Value"] = myValue;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DataRow dr = table.Select("ID=myId").FirstOrDefault(); 
dr["Value"] = "your value";
```

Comment: tried your solution but it throws an error: Cannot find column [myId].

Comment: I think he meant - myId is the Id you are looking for. and why is your ID coming from your database a string?

Comment: NWM solved it :) It actually is not ID it is product code (which can include numbers and letters, that is why it is a string)